# How to implement a 'likes' system

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a liking system for my blog where people get to give a like to a post they enjoyed, so I added a column to the blogs table and named it likes, but this way I won't be able to detect which used liked the post, I though about addind a column for the userID , but that will be limited to one, any idea ?

Comment: This should be a separate table, not a column in your posts table. The Likes table would contain `PostID` and `UserID`, where both are references to the posts table and user table, respectively.

Comment: Study *database normalization*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate table which holds the postid & userid. That way you can have 20 people like the comment but you can query to check if the user already liked it. This is what it should look like in your mysql table:

```
Table (comments)
-----------------
 PostID
 UserID
 Title 
 Content
```

Then a separate table for the likes:

```
Table (likes)
-----------------
 LikeID (Just to make sure you have an index key)
 UserID (This would be the user id of user adding like)
 PostID  (This post id would be from the comments table)
 LikedDate (this is optional)
```

Then when you are adding a like before you do so, do a very simple sql query to check if the userid and postid are already in the likes table. For example:

```
SELECT LikeID FROM likes_table WHERE UserID = ***** AND PostID = *****
```

Then you simply do a php query before adding:

```
if($rows_returned == 0){
 //add the like to likes table
}else{
 //throw an error that the like has already been added
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: perfect, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your likes should be in their own table in order to not violate database architecture rules, particularly the [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form):

```
CREATE TABLE `PostLike` (
    `UserID` CHAR(15) REFERENCES `User`(`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    `PostID` CHAR(15) REFERENCES `Post`(`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE INDEX (`UserID`,`PostID`)
)
```

At this point, your table will automatically reject any inserts thanks to the unique index constraint.

Comment: Thank you ! I dont know how I didn't think about this